# VS Setup Project DefaultLocation for Application Folder

Tags: .net, installation, setup-deployment

I am creating a Setup Project in VS 2008.  The application needs to be supported on Windows 7 running UAC.  I have to install the app in the User's area of the machine.  What do I set the DefaultLocation property of the Application Folder to in the Setup Project?  It can't be set to ProgramFilesFolder.

Comment: You will have to be a lot more specific about where you want the files to go. I think this will be an easy fix once I have that information.

Comment: You should accept an answer or provide some feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Its very simple you can set the default location to where ever you want, but the problem is that it can't be mandatory because using the browse button the end user can navigate to a location as he likes but surely you can set the default location.

1. Right Click the Setup (Project) in the solution explorer.
2. Click View > Click FileSystem.
3. New Interface get opened.
4. Right Click Application Folder Click PropertyWindow.
5. Set DefaultLocation Property to  ie c:\Check.
6. Build the Solution.
7. You are Done.